# Text not showing in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I have 2 div's of text on my website and in IE7 they aren't showing up. The div's are called #cboxlink and #cboxname

In the attached image, you can see the top half of the picture is IE7 and the bottom half is Chrome to see what I mean.

If you go to http://www.directiongroup.com/#work- (on the 'Our Work' part) and click a portfolio item - this is where it is. The portfolio is using jQuery jquery.colorbox.js

Why would 2 simple bits of text not appear in IE? Where in my CSS or jQuery could this problem be?

[image]

Would love some help as I don't really know much about jQuery, many thanks.

Comment: I am using chrome, I dont get `-> view Work` text on some items, and I get it on some others,

Comment: Yeah that's ok, view work only comes up if it's a website job. Carphone is an example of one which has both the link (#cboxlink) and the campaign name (#cboxname).

Comment: ok in that case on css try #cboxName,#cboxlink {display: block !important;} althought I wouldn't advise using this method, but it might be the only way for you.

Comment: @Val thanks just done that and uploaded it to the site for you to see. The background image with 'Campaign name' shows, but the actual text below it doesn't although it's still within the same div #cboxname

Hmm, anything else I could add to the CSS?

Comment: ok gimmie some secs, so that you know you have two doc-types on your html `<div id="formbox">`has a doctype there which should not be aswell, get rid of it in the mean while...

Comment: it looks like there is no text there whats so ever, try and test it if you color box works, on it's own, if it works by it's removing any other script apart from jquery core and ui, then you know it's something else preventing it from working,

Answer (score 1):

In IE the computed display property is set to none, but in FF it's block.  Try adding a rule to force `display:block;`